# Select distinct generate_series postgresql

Tags: postgresql, distinct, generate-series

I know the meaning of distinct and also generate series.
But when I execute this query, question marks are flying around my head.

```
select distinct generate_series(0,8)
```

The result is very weird.

[image]

Can somebody please help me to explain what is happening?

Comment: Why weird result ? The query means "give me a distinct set of values", and a result contains only distinct values. If you want an ordered set, then append `ORDER BY` clause. Could be that PostgeSql builds a hash map in memory to eliminate duplicates, and returns these values ordered by hash.

Comment: @kordirko To someone not used to thinking about the abstractions of query planning, it is surprising that adding a `DISTINCT` can change the order of results. However, your comment is effectively a short version of my answer below. :)

Comment: @IMSoP thank you for comprehensive explanation, +1 from me, since I've learned something new from your answer - I didn't know that the explain shows `HashAggregate` when it is using a hash map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `SELECT` query with no `ORDER BY` clause has *no defined order*, it will simply return the relevant rows in whatever order happens to be convenient to the executing DBMS.

In the case of a "real" table, this might be in order of PRIMARY KEY, in the order they were inserted into the table, or in the order of a particular index that was used in the execution plan.

In this example, the "table" created by `generated_series()` obviously *starts off* in the order 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. However, in order to check the `DISTINCT` constraint you put on the query, Postgres has to do something to check if items appear more than once. (There is no way for it to know that the `generate_series()` function will *always* provide distinct values.)

An efficient way of doing this (in general) is to build a "hash map" of the values you want to check for uniqueness. Rather than checking each new value against every existing value, you calculate which "hash bucket" it would fall into; if the bucket is empty, the value is unique; if not, you need only compare it against the other values in that bucket.

Running `EXPLAIN select distinct generate_series(0,8)` will show you the query plan Postgres has selected; for me (and presumably for you) this looks like this:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=0.02..0.03 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
```

As expected, there's a `HashAggregate` operation there, running over the result of the `generate_series()` in order to check it for uniqueness. (Exactly how that operation works I don't know, and isn't important, but the name strongly suggests it's using a hash map to do the work).

At the end of the hashing operation, Postgres can simply read out the values from the hash map, rather than going back to the original list, so it does so. As a result, they are no longer in the original order, but ordered according to the "hash buckets" they fell into.

The moral of the story is: **Always use an `ORDER BY` clause!**

Comment: Thanx for your responds! However, when i execute this query, it is ordered! select * from generate_series(0,8)
So why should distinct randomize its output?

Comment: Ok... because of hashaggregate.. i think i should learn more about that :)

Comment: @user2513954 You don't really need to know about HashAggregate, just know that if you don't specify an `ORDER BY`, there is *absolutely no guarantee of a particular order*. The DBMS will do whatever it can to process the rest of the query, and whatever order the data happens to be in when it's done that is the order you will see. It just happens that when running `select * from generate_series(0,8)` the data happens to end up in a neat ascending order.

Comment: don't you think that is a bit weird?

Comment: @user2513954 Not really: you didn't ask for an order, so the DBMS didn't define one. The order 0,1,2,3 etc seems "natural" to you, but Postgres doesn't think like a human. Importantly, extending this to more "real life" queries, most queries will not have a neat "natural" order like `generate_series()` does. They'll be retrieving from some index; or a fragmented page of data where rows have been updated, deleted, and re-inserted; or a complex combination of multiple tables and `JOIN` operations.

Comment: Super, thanx for you time and explenation! No my teacher also knows :D :D :D